# Utilização do Data API youtube v2 (Error No longer available)

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando resolver um problema em uma pagina, onde é utilizado a API do youtube, para trazer os videos de um certo canal. porem, recentemente ele comecou a dar o erro **No longer available**.
Não tenho certeza qual a versão do API que esta sendo usado, mas provavelmente é a V2, talvez uma solução seria a migração para a V3, porem eu nao sei como fazer, ja li alguns documentos, Mas nao obtive sucesso.

Alguem ja passou por isso e pode me ajudar?

Alias, estou usando o script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ytEmbed.init({
        'block':'youtubeDiv',
        'paging':false,
        'type':'user',
        'q':'Zenimotors',
        'results':'48',
        'display_first': true, 
        'order':'new_first'
    });
</script>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: O id do canal está correto? As vezes o canal não existe mais...

Comment: Já me certifiquei sobre o canal e ele ainda está ativo, no caso seria o "Zenimotors"

Answer (score 0):

Realmente a `API V2` ja foi descontinuada, você pode migrar para a `V3` usando o [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation) deles